# How would ICO smart contracts function under these scenarios?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, ico

Having been inspired by an idealistic desire to attempt a way forward amidst ongoing diplomatic crises, I hired a team to help me create a mega-infrastructure ICO project at Beringia.io - but I suppose that's besides the point. My questions stem from the fact that, in learning how to interact with this smart contract, I've encountered some curiosities:

1. a) What happens if someone sends ETH to our contract address without ever submitting the purchase details we ask of buyers at Beringia.io – will they still receive BER, or what happens? (the contract address is displayed after the person fills in the information in the screenshot below, and then clicks "buy BER tokens") and b) WHY does this occur?
2. a) What happens if someone DOES register an account at Beringia.io and submits an order but they wait a long time to actually send ETH to the contact address? Is there any time limitation for completing this process? and b) What if the amount of ETH is different from what they said on our ICO site, they never send the ETH, or the valuation of ETH massively changes in the interim?
3. And can only the creator of a coin create contracts? I recently learned to create tokens on my own (albeit via Metamask & [Token Factory](http://tokenfactory.surge.sh)) to help a friend, and sent her 99.99% of the tokens. If she wished to launch an ICO or create a smart contract for some other purpose, would she need access to the original wallet which germinated the smart contact creating the coin, or can any owner create smart contracts with the coin?

Thank you all!

[image: Beringia purchase interface]

Comment: Your first two questions sound like they can only be answered by the person who wrote the ICO contract. I guess that's not you, but surely you know who that is. The answer to your third question is "no" and then "yes." (Anyone can make whatever contract they want.)

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 suggest potentially serious shortcomings at the business process level. Business logic should dictate what gets codified at the contract level. Don't let the tail wag the dog.

Comment: @smarx So, there's no particular set of standards baked into Ethereum regarding questions 1 & 2, but they are items that should be addressed in any ICO smart contract? I suppose it wouldn't hurt to find out by attempting these scenarios myself, but I've also asked the folks who built it.

Comment: @smarx And for my 3rd question, that's good to know that my friend could set up an ICO contract, etc, without needing possession of my wallet - but if I were a bad actor, as the person owning the wallet which signed the contract creating the token, could I mess things up for her, even if she owned 99-100% of the coin. E.g. As the contract originator, would I be able to burn and mint coins, messing with the supply of her coin, etc. As you can likely tell, I'm new to Ethereum contracts, so apologies for any questions that are basic in nature.

Comment: @KenChester An Ethereum token is just a smart contract. The code in the smart contract dictates what you and she can do. (E.g. the smart contract could have a "stealAllTokens()" function that returns them all to your possession.) So again, you'd have to read the code to know what this particular contract does.

Comment: @smarx So assuming no sinister intentions on behalf of neither myself nor the creators of Token Factory (http://tokenfactory.surge.sh/#/factory), which helped me write the contract creating the token, my friend would have nothing to fear about someone suddenly destroying her ICO project if a bad actor somehow took control of my wallet (which wrote the contract creating her token, yet subsequently sent her nearly all of the tokens). Considering this, it would appear she's safe, even if I were careless with my wallet.